# Highlighting smallest Value, if not within X of second smallest value in column group?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I can highlight the smallest value in each row of a `column group` of an SSRS tablix with no issue by adding a hidden `Min(Value)` column outside the group and comparing it using `ReportItem!MinVale.Value`.

The column is calculated as:

```
=IIF(Fields!TotalSales.Value=0
     ,0
     ,Fields!Sales.Value / IIF(Fields!TotalSales.Value<>0
                               ,Fields!TotalSales.Value
                               ,1
                               )
     )
```

I have been asked to only highlight it if it is less by a margin of 1% or more.

[image: sample results]

This record should not be highlighted as it is only .02% less than the next lowest value.

I cannot figure out a way to calculate the second lowest value for comparison and trying to google it hasn't turned up anything either.

Is it possible to calculate the second smallest value in each row within a column group?

(If possible I would like to avoid changing the underlying TSql query to rank the results in a new field to highlight based on that as this s a small part of a far larger set of reports.)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    RowId VARCHAR(20),
    Field1 INT,
    Field2 INT,
    Field3 INT,
    Field4 INT
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
('A', 1, 2, 3, 4 ),
('B', 2, 3, 4, 1 ),
('C', 3, 4, 1, 2 ),
('D', 4, 1, 2, 3 )


SELECT m.*,
    u.FieldName,
    u.ValueRank
FROM @MyTable m
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT u.RowId,
        u.FieldName,
        u.Value,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY u.RowId ORDER BY VALUE DESC) ValueRank
    FROM @MyTable
    UNPIVOT
    (
        Value
        for FieldName in (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
    ) u
) u
ON u.RowId = m.RowId
AND u.ValueRank = 2
```

Here is the output:

```
RowId   Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  FieldName   ValueRank
A   1   2   3   4   Field3  2
B   2   3   4   1   Field2  2
C   3   4   1   2   Field1  2
D   4   1   2   3   Field4  2
```

I unpivoted the columns so I could rank the values and then I pull only the 2nd from last rank (order by desc) to find which column had the 3 value.  You can use this same technique to order columns in a row from least to most, etc.

Comment: this is not in SSRS column group, as i said this is 2 columns coming out of a huge query that I would prefer not to change. TY for the effort though.